# How to delete GIT branch from master in remote repo and start a new branch from another branch?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

I accidentally created a new branch from master branch in origin and committed my changes to that branch.

Let's call the new branch I created `Accidental_Branch`.

But I was supposed to create the new branch from a different branch, let's say `Feature_Branch`. Master branch is not up to date and my team commits all the changes to `Feature_Branch` from which I was supposed to create the new branch. This is what I want.

1. Delete the branch I created, ie `Accidental_Branch`. I don't want to lose changes I made in my local since I want to create a new branch with that change.
2. Create a new branch from `Feature_Branch`. And commit changes. Changes meaning, changes I have committed to `Accidental_Branch` and my uncommitted changes in local.

Please help me out. I am new to GIT.

Comment: If I get your question right, Git offers [Branch Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) for that. From your question I'd say it is to rebase `Accidental_Branch` onto `Feature_Branch` from `Master` (or `master`, not entirely clear from your question). That is then any changes (commits) you made since Master in `Accidental_Branch` are rebased on top of `Feature_Branch` then. You can then rename the `Accidental_Branch` (or keep it's name as assumable it is not "Accidental" in the real name and the real name is fitting already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save uncommitted changes, you can generate a [stash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash) (cashing the selected files) with `git stash save "optional stash-message"`.

So you can caching your files and so you don‘t lose them. After `git stash` you can delete the accidentally generated branch by `git branch -d <branch_name>` local and for remote deleting `git push origin --delete <branch_name>`.

Checked out the branch where you will start your new branch (`git checkout <branch_name>`) and create there your *new* branch with `git branch <branch_name>` and checked out this as explain above and then apply your generated stash with `git stash apply stash@{0}`.

How `git stash` works is simple explained on this [website-blog](https://www.sitepoint.com/git-simply-stashing/).

### EDIT, WHY QUESTION IS NOT REALLY CLEAR ENOUGH:

If the changes in your accidentally branch already pushed to remote server, so `git stash` doesn‘t work. In this case, you must [revert](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/commands/git-revert/) the commit, that include your changes where you don‘t want to lose. The `git revert` command will create new changes with the *opposite* effect and thereby undo the specified old commit, so the changes are available again and not lost.

After `git revert` you have your changed files in the working directory and you can create the new branch. If the new branch starts in another branch, you must *stash* the uncommited files again, create and checkout the new generated branch and *apply the stash* in this branch as explain above.

Comment: I have pushed the changes to the remote server. I want to undo that and also don't want to lose those changes in my local. Please tell me if my understanding is correct: I have to first stash all my changes. Then revert the commit I made in the remote. Create a new branch from my required branch and apply stash. Then commit changes to the new branch in origin and delete the accidental branch I created. Is it right?

Comment: First `git revert` is for reverting the changes in origin right? Then what is the second `git revert` for?

Comment: Before `git revert` you must first stash the changed files (for local uncommitted changes). Then `git revert` and then stash again the files where comes from the git revert (now you have 2 stashes (show all stashes with git stash list)). Then checkout the branch where you will start the new one, create the new one and checkout the new one. Then apply both stashes and you will have all changed files in the new branch!

Comment: Ok.Got it. Thank you. You saved my life:)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to lose the uncommited data, you can temporarily but safely save the data using the `$ git stash` command. This will store the data in a hidden place.
After that, you can switch between branches or create a new branch using `$ git checkout -b {new_branch_name}`

Now, you will be landed at the new branch. In this branch, you can get the data that is stashed before using the `$ git stash apply` command.

After that, you can safely delete the previously created branch using the following commands:

For deleting the local branch use the following command:

`$ git branch -d {branch_name}`

You can force delete the branch using the -D option as follows:

`$ git branch -D {branch_name}`

You can delete the remote branch using the following command:

`$ git push origin --delete {branch_name}`

See if this is what you are looking for. But you had also said in your question that you had committed changes to the branch. If you had committed changes then stashing will not work. Please clear your question a bit in that case. It will be great if you can state the branch names in your question.

Comment: And where are the changes that are in the accidental branch that the questioner does not want to lose? In your example, these changes are simply deleted by removing this branch `git branch -d {branch_name}`, and that isn‘t what the questioner will...

Comment: I had updated the answer. But the questioner had said that he already commit changes to the branch. In that case, the git stash will not work.

Comment: Yes of course, the question is not clearly enough...

Comment: @Ankush Chavan I have edited the question to make it clear. I hope now you understand my situation. Yes, I have committed my changes in origin and also there are some uncommitted changes in my local. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can just rebase the commits you created onto the location you want.

Depending on how many there are, it may be easier to manually create a new branch, cherry pick them one at a time and delete the old one.